# How is this computed?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

$ \left| 1-e^{-is\lambda} \right|^2 = 2 (1-cos\lambda s)$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

I don't know how to work with $i$.

Thanks

Comment: By that: $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

Comment: Also $|a + bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and those should be the only relations you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda s =t$. Then 
\begin{align}
| 1 - e^{-it}|^2 &= 2(1 - \cos t) \\
\iff |1 - \cos t + i \sin t|^2 &= 2(1 - \cos t) \\
\iff (1 - \cos t)^2 + \sin ^2 t &= 2(1 - \cos t) \\
\iff \sin ^2 t + \cos ^2 t &= 1
\end{align}